# Configure multi site on nginx server through IP using Digital Ocean

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, nginx-config

Problem: Unable to hit two websites handled under one nginx server i.e. `<<ip-address>>` & `<<ip-address>>/web2`

Configuration on Digital Ocean:

1. 1 Droplet / Ubuntu 18 / LEMP
2. I have two test PHP website in the CodeIgniter framework
3. Folder config for 1st Website: `/var/www/html/web1/`
4. Folder config for 2nd Website: `/var/www/html/web2/`

Nginx Server Block configuration for two sites

**web1.com**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/web1;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name <<ip-address>>;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

**web2.com**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/web2;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name <<ip-address>>/web2;

        location /web2/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

I am totally new to nginx server, I do according to the documentation provided by a community under a digital ocean.

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: So, the problem is that nothing works? You end up on the same site on both urls? You end up on a 404 page?

Comment: Yes, it's not working.
Both URL should hit the different website
Currently, it tries to find `web2` as controller from `web1` site, hence giving an error.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not how nginx works out of the box. It could, with a lot of fiddling, end up working that way, but I don't think it's worth the effort.

See, nginx configuration expects `server_name` to be either a FQDN (fully qualified domain name) or an IP address, but not a full URL with path.
In your case, the request for ip-address/web2 is probably actually matching web1's config (so pointing you to `/var/www/html/web1/web2/` which doesn't exist)

Best way to work this out (assuming you want to keep both sites on the same droplet): get a FQDN for each site. It could be a subdomain for a domain you already have (i.e. web1.sharad.com and web2.sharad.com)... Then on each of nginx's config files use the appropriate server name (web1.sharad.com and web2.sharad.com), check for typos and errors with `sudo nginx -t` and if all is OK restart nginx with `sudo systemctl restart nginx`